PCB footprint design for minimum solder use
Are there any studies that show how to design a footprint for minimum solder use?
I'm looking at an application where many millions of solder points per day will be running.
Obviously there's a minimum amount of solder to perform a good joint, and to pull the components to center.   Lowering the solder mass will save costs, but if it starts inducing bad solder joints then that gets expensive too.

Your salary is most likely much higher than the potential solder paste savings you can tweak out, even when not considering the potential risk of burning hours troubleshooting boards with bad soldering as a consequence of being greedy with the paste. Use IPC compliant footprints or the footprint from the datasheet of the part, and you're most likely to create a board that solders well.

I guess, you are looking in the wrong spot for reducing assembly cost.
Even if you manage to reduce the solder mass to an optimal minimum, your assembly house won't quote a lower price most likely. In fact, most assembly houses will modify your stencil pattern for optimal solder joint quality anyway.
